# How to remove &nbsp; from json data and show pure Text in React App

Tags: javascript, regex

I have retrieved my json data into my react native app. I have removed the html tags with this code

```
const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
const result = params.matan.replace(regex, "");
```

But still I can see `&nbsp;` or spaces between my paragraphs.

How to remove this `&nbsp;` from it. What else to add in my regex to remove also the `&nbsp;`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would rather create an HTML element, assign the HTML you have to its `innerHTML` and then read out the `innerText`:

```
const html = params.matan // your HTML code
const el = document.createElement('div')
el.innerHTML = html
const text = el.innerText
```

For an HTML as follows

```
<p>Hello&nbsp;World</p>

<p>Test 123</p>
```

it would return

```
Hello World

Test 123
```

Comment: not working. I am using react native not react js. how to implement it in react native

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery, parse the HTML

```
jQuery.parseHTML()
```

Comment: OP is using react, so a plain js solution would be nice